# How can I populate different forms into one variable at different times SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to have the option to pass 1 of 5 different forms into a variable of another view. The issue I am facing is what data type to make the variable of the form being passed in ('form' in this case). Is there a way to have multiple form structs with the same data type?

CustomForm Struct

```
struct CustomForm: View {
@State private var field1: String = ""
@State private var field2: String = ""
var body: some View {
    Form {
        TextField("Field 1", text: $field1)
        TextField("Field 2", text: $field2)
    }
  }
}
```

Test View where form is being populated

```
struct Test: View {
  @State private var form: CustomForm = CustomForm()
  var body: some View {
      self.form
  }
}
```

What I have here work perfect fine with one form. How would I go about changing the value of the variable `form` to a different form view?

Comment: Would you show how are you going to construct/use those different forms? I feel the approach might be different.

Answer (score 0):

**there are some ways to do what you want, one of them:**

you can erase types of view by using `AnyView`.
for example if you have a form:

```
Form {
// form content here
}
```

you can assign it to a variable:

```
let form1 = Form {
// form content here
}
```

then you can add it to an array on `AnyView`s:

```
var arrayOfForms: [AnyView] = [
AnyView(form1),
AnyView(form2),
AnyView(form3),
AnyView(form4)
]
```

then choose and show the appropriate view

Comment: How can I add TextFields in the form? The second parameter  of a TextField, `text:`, needs to be set to a @State variable to capture the value.